# Method not found in instantiated class (Ruby/Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, activerecord, activeresource

So I come from a background in Java where you can create a class as such.

```
TestClass x = new TextClass();
```

and call its method like 
    x.shout();

I'm attempting to do something similar in ruby with no such look. This could be syntactical or it could be I don't understand the concept of ruby and rails well.

So heres a class on a server in Ruby

```
class myResource< ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:3008"
  def self.shout
    puts "I AM AN ACTIVE RESOURCE SHOUT!"
    puts " CAPS RAGE YEAH!"
    puts Time.now
  end
end
```

This sits on client side.

Heres the same class as an active record on server:

```
class myRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.shout
  puts "I AM AN ACTIVE RECORD SHOUT!"
  puts " CAPS RAGE YEAH!"
  puts Time.now
  end

end
```

So heres the result of what I've attempted.

On server in rails console:

```
?> myRecord.shout
I AM AN ACTIVE RECORD SHOUT!
 CAPS RAGE YEAH!
Wed Jul 13 10:17:33 +0100 2011
=> nil
>>
```

On the client side however,

```
myResource.shout
NoMethodError: undefined method `shout' for myResource:Class
    from (irb):206
>>
```

In my mind this makes no sense as their almost identical and should be called as such.

If i instantiate either of them as

```
@test = myResource or myRecord.new(blah blah blah)
```

when i write @test.shout

I get the same undefined method.

My idea of what an object is in Ruby has been blown. Has anyone any advice on what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Your code shouldn't work at all. Class names must start with a capital letter.

Comment: @dogbert. Hello. I love your cartoon. They original classes do start with capital letters. I was rushing through writing this question and didnt spot that. Apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby classes are always capitalized. Also, you do not reference self when you are declaring a regular method in a class.

This is what you want:

```
class MyRecord 

    def shout
        puts "I AM AN ACTIVE RECORD SHOUT!"
        puts "CAPS RAGE YEAH!"
        puts Time.now
    end

end
```

Then run it however you want:

```
> MyRecord.new.shout
=> "I AM AN ACTIVE RECORD SHOUT!"
=> "CAPS RAGE YEAH!"
=> 2011-07-13 06:35:18 -0400
```

Comment: NP:) `def method.self` is used for singleton method in modules. That will make more sense when you have mixins.

Comment: I was under the impression that self methods were class methods (as opposed to instance methods)?